# What is wrong with this?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, copy-constructor, rtti

The assignment does not seem to work. Compiler is telling me is can't find the right constructor.

```
Course::Course(Course& course){
    if(dynamic_cast<ExamAssessment*>(course.assessment) != NULL){
        assessment = new ExamAssessment(*(course.assessment));
    }
```

This code is inside the copy constructor of a course class

*part of the class*

```
class Course{
    char* courseName;
   float fee;

public:
    Assessment* assessment;
```

Assessment is a base class that has 3 sub classes(ExamAssessment as 1 of them). In The cpp file of ExamAssessment, I have a copy consructor

```
ExamAssessment::ExamAssessment(ExamAssessment& exam){
    examMark = exam.examMark;
    CalculateGrade();
}
```

Obviously the parameter in the assignment is wrong but I'm not sure why(new to C++).

Comment: c++ is case sensitive. `course.assessment!= Course.Assessment`

Comment: Should have mentioned that the parameter takes a reference to a course... course is just the variable name

Comment: Also, can you show us the line you declare course.assessment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the result of the cast and use it as your constructor parameter. Your `course.assessment` may be an `ExamAssessment` behind the scenes, but the datatype is still `Assessment` and you don't have a constructor using that type.

Comment: So should I cast it inside the constructor parameter?

Comment: Got it working thx :). Just printing garbage somewhere but it's unrelated to this problem xD